# videoJS - play without fully load video

Tags: php, video.js

I have a php file, where I download a flv file by parties, like that:

```
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header ("Content-Length: " . $length);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.flv");

$fd = fopen($url, "r");
while(!feof($fd))
{
    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    ob_flush();
}
```

Then this video is playing on my web page using videoJS:

```
<body>
    <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" width="640" height="480"
        data-setup='{"loadingSpinner": false, "controls" : true, "autoplay" : true, "preload" : "auto"}'>
        <source src="videos.php" type="video/x-flv">
    </video>
</body>
```

But when I scroll a time display video for: 1:12:14, the time counter is stop and the video exacly is on 00:03:14 (but pointer is still on 1:12:14).

I want fix this error - if file isn't load to 1:12:14 - player should block change time display.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

When you click fast forward with the video player, the browser will cancel the existing request and make a new request for only a portion of
the file. The "Range" header is present in this new request. In this case, the server must respond with status code 206
(Partial Content) and include the "Content-Range" header.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
  // extract the range string
  list ($units, $range) = explode ("=", $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']);
  list ($firstByte, $lastByte) = explode ("-", $range);
  $length = $lastByte - $firstByte + 1; // Calculate a new content length
  // seek forward on the file
  fseek ($fd, $firstByte);

  // headers to return for partial content
  header ("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
  header ("Content-Range: bytes $firstByte-$lastByte/$size");
  header ("Content-Length: $length");
}
```

See "14.35 Range" at:
   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't fix my problem. I added your code in te first lines, before headers in php file but it still doesn't work. I think, RANGE header is not sending.
 Look here: http://majk23.vot.pl/filmy/